# RegEx extract website url from email address w/ sub-sub-domain

Tags: php, regex

We are trying to extract from an email list a valid url for that organization.

`abc@charleston.k12.il.us` is easy, but sometimes we have 
`someone@u40gw.effingham.k12.il.us` where the `040gw` is a subdomain for internal mail.

Another example is `someone@mail.meridian223.org` or `someone@athletics.msstate.edu`

What would be the most efficient way to capture the `.edu` + the preceding name only, without additional subdomains, or in the case of high schools the whole part `k12.il.us` plus the preceding name only?

Tried so far:

```
/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)|@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]*))/
```

Comment: Leave your question more clear, please.

Comment: @egekhter "in the case of high schools"?! What is the exact rule here? Does PHP know which domains are high schools? Or do you expect regex to have some certain syntax for that?

Comment: Could be a combination, I was wondering if this could be a purely regex solution, but I can use multiple regex and then if $matches[i] = 'k12', then I would proceed with that rule, otherwise I would use one of the other rules.

Comment: p.s. why the down votes (for future reference)

Comment: @egekhter Be clear on what you really demand, not only in the code you want to spend, you can not understand what you mean by "school"
be clear about what we really need your software.

Comment: In its simplest form, to convert a email address from known organizations into the organization's corresponding website url

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of brute force code... you could "explode" the part after the "@" and attempt an fopen on "www" + the an implode of the explode. Dropping the first element of the array on each error. This would allow you to capture when a subdomain email has it's own website as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex pattern:

```
@.*?([^.]+[.]\w{3}|[^.]+[.]k12[.]il[.]us)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Where, you can replace `\w{3}` with your list of possible extensions, like `org`, `edu`, `net` etc. An example would be like:

```
@.*?([^.]+[.](edu|org|net|info|com)|[^.]+[.]k12[.]il[.]us)$
```

You can see it working on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/38sj2)

Comment: This solution is elegant, simple, and powerful at the same time. This answer will provide a good platform for seeing how regex can be used for common problems. Thank you!

Comment: Ah someone else that uses `[.]` instead of `\.`! It looks so much cleaner some of the time (I assume a character class may have somewhat of a performance decrease compared to an escaped literal, but I still do this most of the time).